# Get body of post request vert.x javascript verticle

Tags: javascript, rest, post, vert.x

Pasted below is the code of my javascript verticle which is deployed successfully. Since I couldn't find a way to debug the js verticle, I printed all the properties of the routingContext for reference. I am trying to get body of the request, however all the functions starting with `getBody` are returning null. I have pasted the request I am making below the code, with the log printed in the intellij terminal. Am I doing something wrong?

**JS Verticle Code**

```
var Router = require("vertx-web-js/router");
var server = vertx.createHttpServer();
var router = Router.router(vertx);
function writeHelp(obj) {
    var txt = "";
    for (var x in obj){
        txt += x + "->" + obj[x] + "\n";
    }
    return txt;
}
router.post("/provider").handler(function (routingContext) {
    var response = routingContext.response();
    var json = routingContext.getBodyAsString();
    response.putHeader("content-type", "text/plain");
    //console.log("Helper\n" + writeHelp(routingContext));
    //console.log("Request=" + writeHelp(routingContext.request()));
    console.log("body=" + json);
    response.end("Success");
});
server.requestHandler(router.accept).listen(8890);
```

**POST Request made through ARC**

[image]

**Log from Intellij**

```
Router: 257219241 accepting request POST http://localhost:8890/provider 
Route matches: Route[ path:/provider pattern:null handler:io.vertx.core.Handler$$NashornJavaAdapter@69b539e failureHandler:null order:0 methods:[POST]]@32182409 
Calling the  handler 
body=null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the [BodyHandler](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/js/#_request_body_handling) to get parsed body:

From the official documentation:

```
var BodyHandler = require("vertx-web-js/body_handler");

// This body handler will be called for all routes
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create().handle);
```

Comment: while I have you, do you know a way of debugging a javascript verticle in intellij?

Comment: vertx uses [nashorn](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html) as javascript interpreter to be run js code on the jvm, try to google about it, I guess there is should be the solution like idea plugins or something else. Here is an [example](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/debugger-for-jdk8s-nashorn-javascript-in-intellij-idea-13-1/) I found.